# Impedir usuário de copiar aplicação android

Tags: android

Baixei um programa chamado apk share no playstore, esse aplicativo copia o apk de qualquer programa que estiver instalado no dispositivo android. A questão é como não permitir que esse aplicativo faça o backup das informações?

Sei que existem programas como o avast anti vírus que tem opção de bloquear o uso de alguns programas, mas o problema é que se o usuário baixar meu app do play store ele poderá copiá-lo através do apkshare e distribuir gratuitamente para outras pessoas.

Nas configurações do Manifest existe um atributo chamado android:allowBackup, mas pelo o que eu entendo esse atributo só permite ou não o backup do aplicativo  em nuvem. Até porque eu deixei essa opção desativada e mesmo assim consegui copiar o meu apk.

Comment: Se você não quer que ele seja distribuído de graça o que você tem que fazer é bloquear do seu lado, criando uma autenticação única por compra/usuário/acesso/id do dispositivo/seja lá o que mais. Você querer bloquear isso sem esse tipo de validação é burrice.

Comment: Isso que @MaiconCarraro falou é o mínimo. Até porque se seu aplicativo realmente vale a pena, os caras abrem o apk e removem esse bloqueio. Infelizmente a realidade é que se você não quer que seu aplicativo possa ser "pirateado", não publique.

Comment: Calma, galera... Sou ciente de todos esses fatos. Soh queria reforçar com mais profissionais sobre esse assunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É muito difícil fazer com que o APK tenha 100% de proteção pelos seguintes motivos:

- Qualquer usuário com um telefone *rooteado* pode copiar seu APK e estudá-lo.
- Com ferramentas como [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) e [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) se pode ver todo o código fonte em seus APKs.
- Mesmo que a maioria dos identificadores de código-fonte compilado não forneçam as classes com os nomes corretos, um bom programador poderia descobrir o que o seu aplicativo faz.
- Qualquer pessoa desonesta pode copiar o seu código fonte (utilizando o jd-gui por exemplo), transferí-lo para o Android Studio e criar um app inteiramente baseado no seu.
- Qualquer pessoa pode fazer engenharia reversa no seu aplicativo, até por que nõ é tão difícil deduzir como um aplicativo foi escrito olhando apenas para a sua interface.

Portanto, o ideal seria que você focasse na construção de aplicativos  tão bons e com um grau de inovação tão alto, que ninguém possa acompanhar seu desenvolvimento. Para isso, procure escrever códigos que sejam faceis de entender, expandir e realizar manutenção, pois essas são as principais características dos melhores apps do mercado.